# How to move object from a function return correctly?

Tags: c++, c++11, return, move, temporary-objects

I have an Object that should not be copied, but only moved, and so I've tried to ensure that a function returns the `T&&` of the object. My problem is that the object is being destroyed before it returns and I don't know how to do this properly.

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{public:
    Foo() { 
        a = new int; 
        std::cout << a << '\n'; 
    }
    Foo(const Foo& other) = delete;
    Foo(Foo&& other) { 
        a = other.a; other.a = nullptr; 
    }
    ~Foo() { 
        std::cout << a << '\n';
        delete a; 
    }
    void operator= (const Foo& other) = delete;
    void operator= (Foo&& other) { 
        a = other.a; 
        other.a = nullptr; 
    }
    int* a;
};

Foo&& createNewFoo()
{
    return std::move(Foo());
}

int main()
{
    Foo foo = createNewFoo(); // The pointer is deleted before this assigns to foo

}
```

Comment: Btw. `void operator=()` looks a bit strange. I'm used to the return type reference (i.e. `return *this;`). [Canonical implementations - Assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Assignment_operator)

Comment: Seconding what Scheff said.  The `void operator=()` is legal and allowed, but it is non-idiomatic, which increases the friction for any other developer using that object. Because it will behave in surprising and unusual ways. It's a **suggestion**, it's not a **rule** to do it that usual way, there may be good reasons to have an atypical implementation.

Answer (score 4):

You're constructing a temporary object and binding it to the rvalue-reference as the return value, the temporary will be destroyed after the full expression immediately then the returned reference is always dangled.

Changing the function to return-by-value would be fine; rvalue would be moved to the return value.

```
Foo createNewFoo()
{
    return Foo();
}
```

BTW: For the above code, `Foo foo = createNewFoo();` won't copy/move anything due to [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision), which is guaranteed since C++17.

**EDIT**

> So why isn't the temporary destroyed immediately when returning `return Foo();`

For return-by-value, the order of returning is

1. construct the temporary
2. move-construct the return value from the temporary
3. temporary gets destroyed

For return-by-reference, the order is

1. construct the temporary
2. bind the temporary to return value
3. temporary gets destroyed
4. return value (the reference) becomes dangled

Comment: So why isn't the temporary destroyed immediately when returning return Foo(); Are references destroyed before assigning whereas returning the object itself means destroying it after?

Comment: I see. When you say "return value" in those steps you mean temporary value that's created from the function before it's assigned to foo in Foo foo = createNewFoo(); right? So essentially, assuming no optimizations, returning by value, there's a move from the local temporary to the return value, and then another move from that to foo in Foo foo = createNewFoo(); ?

Comment: @Zebrafish Yes, there's 2 moves (in concept before C++17). (And both are elided in fact.)

Answer (score 2):

You can just do the following:

```cpp
static Foo createNewFoo() {
    return Foo();
}
```

Since `Foo()` is already an r-value, no `std::move` is needed.

Comment: Foo() is not rvalue reference! It is not reference at all.

Comment: @IgorR. sorry, I wrote a wrong thing while wanting to be fast. Answer updated